# Java instancing an interface results Odd behavior

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, abstract-class

I am just wandering if following is an odd behaviour.

```
public interface TestInterfaceTwo {         
    public void sayBye();
}


public interface TestInterfaceOne {         
    public void sayHI();
}


public abstract class TestIntefaceClass implements TestInterfaceOne, TestInterfaceTwo {
    @Override   
    public void sayHI() {       
        System.out.println("HI");
    }

    @Override 
    public void sayBye() {
        System.out.println("Bye");
    }
}


public class InterfaceImplementer extends TestIntefaceClass{    
    @Override
    public void sayHI() {
        System.out.println("SAY HI");
    }
}
```

---

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     InterfaceImplementer impl  = new InterfaceImplementer();
     TestInterfaceOne impl1 = new InterfaceImplementer();
     TestInterfaceTwo impl2 = new InterfaceImplementer(); 
     TestIntefaceClass impl3 = new  InterfaceImplementer();     

     impl.sayHI(); 
     impl.sayBye();
     impl1.sayHI();
     impl2.sayBye();
     impl.sayBye();
     impl3.sayBye();
     impl3.sayHI();
 }
```

These calls result the following

```
SAY HI
Bye
SAY HI
Bye
Bye
Bye
SAY HI
```

I needed to know if interface instances inherit only the expected behavior from the interface or if it inherits the abstract class. It seems it does the latter and I would like to know an explanation for this and if it is bug Or a feature. :)

Comment: 1. make your code readable, 1 command per line!!! 2. add your question, i cant understand what u ask

Comment: Just did..:) realized that I have used wrong button Thanks for the comment

Comment: it inherits from abstract class. So AbstractClass is like Parent and your InterfaceImplementer is child of your abstract class. So its like child (say human child) inheriting genes and some features from his/her parents.

Comment: what's your question exactly ? are you expecting a result and you got a different one ? what result did u get ?

Comment: Some one had edited my question just as I edited the question to add the response so lost it. Edited to add it.. :) Thanks for the response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works as expected. I am not entirely sure what is that confuses you.

> I needed to know if interface instances inherit only the expected behavior from the interface or if it inherits the abstract class. It seems it does the latter and I would like to know an explanation for this and if it is bug Or a feature. :)

Interfaces don't implement any 'behaviour' (although Java 8 provides [default methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html)) and you can't instantiate one. All those instances you're creating are class instances - in your case, instances of `InterfaceImplementer`. So let's look at this class and its parent:

`TestIntefaceClass` implements two interfaces and their methods. Nothing special here.

`InterfaceImplementer` extends `TestIntefaceClass` class, it inherits the implementation of `sayBye()` but it provides its own implementation of `sayHi()`.

Now the following (and the other similar examples from your code)

```
TestInterfaceOne impl = new InterfaceImplementer();
```

creates an instance of `InterfaceImplementer`, as you can see on the right hand side. Thus the implementations that will be used when calling `sayHi()` and `sayBye()` will be the ones that `Interfaceimplementer` overrides / inherits.

LE: [This link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceAsType.html) will probably be useful to you. It discusses using interfaces as types, which is what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

the "new InterfaceImplementer()" is giving you exactly that ... its just you are decalring them as the various ways .... it's working as expected